# Are these functions in the Kotlin Collections standard library duplicated, or do they have subtle differences?

Tags: collections, kotlin

I'm wondering if there is any difference at all between the functions

```
// Returns true if the collection is empty
fun <T> Collection<T>.isEmpty(): Boolean
```

and

```
// Returns true if the collection has no elements
fun <T> Iterable<T>.none(): Boolean
```

Are there any subtle differences between these two? For example that a Collection containing nulls can be considered empty, or that Collection/Iterable makes a difference? How would calling these two functions on for example a List be different? Would any of these two be different from calling

```
!list.any()
```

or

```
list.size() == 0
```

I'm also wondering if there is any difference between the two functions

```
operator fun <T> Iterable<T>.plus(element: T): List<T>
```

and

```
fun <T> Iterable<T>.plusElement(element: T): List<T>
```

If not, what's the reason for all the duplicity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Not every `Iterable` is a `Collection`. If you look at `none()` implementation, you'll see that when used in a collection instance, it actually calls `Collection.isEmpty`:

```
/**
 * Returns `true` if the collection has no elements.
 */
public fun <T> Iterable<T>.none(): Boolean {
    if (this is Collection) return isEmpty()
    return !iterator().hasNext()
}
```

2 - Is [operator overloading](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html). `operator fun <T> Iterable<T>.plus(element: T): List<T>` is adding the `+` operator to `Iterable`, so you can do:

```
val iterable: Iterable<String> = ...
val newIterable = iterable + "newItem"
```

Comment: 2 - I guess I still don't understand the reason for having two different functions. If you only had the operator overloading one, you could still choose to call it like

    val newIterable = iterable + "newItem" or
    val newIterable = iterable.plus("newItem")

so what is the purpose of the second function plusElement()?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an [implementation of `Iterable<T>.none()`](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.2.40/libraries/stdlib/src/generated/_Collections.kt#L1707):

```
public fun <T> Iterable<T>.none(): Boolean {
    if (this is Collection) return isEmpty()
    return !iterator().hasNext()
}
```

As you may notice, it calls `Collection<T>.isEmpty()` if the implementation is a `Collection`.

The difference in the semantics is that `none()` can try to iterate over the container to find out that it has no elements (i.e. it just uses `iterator()`), while `isEmpty()` is provided with custom implementation in the concrete `Collection` subtypes.

Answer (score 0):

### none and any

functions like `none()` or `any()` are mostly used with a predicate function to test if *any* element matches the predicate or *none* respectively.

I assume the methods without are there for consistency reasons.

### operator keyword

The operator keyword shows you that this function implements an operator. Here the `+` operator so you can use the plus-sign to add elements to any Iterator and return a new List, whereas you have to use the method `plusElement` by name to add elements to the iterable/list.

```
val listOfFour = listOf(1,2,3) + 4
```

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html